# fundamentally Is there any changes between the asp.net and sql-server with old .Net framework 3.5 to 4.8 in the 2023?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

just i want to make sure that the fundamentals of asp.net are changed between the .Net framework version 3.5 to 4.8 and SQL-server all the fundamentals are outdated, and even in 2023 all the fundamentals of asp.net and SQL-server still apply now with old .net framework 3.5 to 4.8 or not? please help me.

Comment: If you're looking to do *new* development, Microsoft's recommendation is to be looking at .NET 6. Whilst you *can* do new development in .NET Framework 4.8, it's probably a bad idea.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.